# Power BI DAX to filter common items A & B share

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Sample data:

```
| Vendor | Size Group | Model | Quantity | Cost  | TAT | Posting Date      | 
|--------|------------|-------|----------|-------|-----|-------------------| 
| A      | S          | A150  | 150      | 450   | 67  | July 7, 2018      | 
| A      | M          | A200  | 250      | 1500  | 75  | June 22, 2018     | 
| A      | M          | A150  | 25       | 8500  | 85  | July 9, 2018      | 
| C      | L          | A200  | 350      | 1250  | 125 | March 5, 2018     | 
| C      | XL         | A500  | 150      | 6500  | 45  | February 20, 2018 | 
| A      | M          | A900  | 385      | 475   | 40  | January 29, 2018  | 
| A      | M          | A150  | 650      | 45    | 45  | August 31, 2018   | 
| D      | M          | A150  | 65       | 7500  | 15  | April 10, 2018    | 
| D      | M          | A300  | 140      | 3420  | 10  | April 3, 2018     | 
| E      | S          | A150  | 20       | 10525 | 85  | January 3, 2018   | 
| B      | S          | A150  | 30       | 10500 | 40  | June 3, 2018      | 
| B      | S          | A150  | 450      | 450   | 64  | April 3, 2018     | 
| E      | XS         | A900  | 45       | 75    | 60  | January 3, 2018   | 
| F      | M          | A900  | 95       | 655   | 175 | January 3, 2018   | 
| D      | XL         | A300  | 15       | 21500 | 25  | January 3, 2018   | 
| D      | S          | A500  | 450      | 65    | 25  | May 3, 2018       | 
| A      | M          | A350  | 250      | 450   | 22  | January 3, 2018   | 
| B      | S          | A150  | 45       | 8500  | 28  | January 3, 2018   | 
| A      | S          | A300  | 550      | 650   | 128 | January 3, 2018   | 
| C      | M          | A150  | 1500     | 855   | 190 | January 3, 2018   | 
| B      | M          | A150  | 65       | 1750  | 41  | January 3, 2018   | 
| A      | L          | A500  | 75       | 1700  | 24  | January 3, 2018   | 
| B      | S          | A900  | 55       | 9800  | 37  | May 29, 2018      | 
| B      | M          | A500  | 150      | 850   | 83  | April 18, 2018    |
```

In the provided sample, the common Size Groups A & B both share are S & M. So, I was hoping to display those Size Groups as the legend and Average Cost as the value in a clustered column chart.

Can anyone please advise how I can go about this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I don't know how to display only the common groups between A & B in a graph

Comment: What about `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`? Are those on your chart?

Comment: Perhaps a table with your desired output would be helpful?

Comment: @AlexisOlson No, I don't want C D E F to be on my chart. I only want to filter A & B and show all items that they share.